# How do I make the text move to the right?

Tags: c

I have written a code where the output should be moved a little bit to the right like this: 
http://imageshack.com/a/img537/9765/7uQXuY.jpg

but my code turned out to be like this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img540/2117/mpK85j.jpg

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n, c, k, space = 1;
  char ch='a';

  printf(" Enter the size of the diamond:\t");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  space = n - 1;

  for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
  {
    for (c = 1; c <= space; c++)
      printf(" ");

    space--;
    ch='`'; /* starting from the Asci code num 096 */


    for (c = 1; c <= 2*k-1; c++)

      if (c <= k)
      {ch++;
      printf("%c", ch);
      }

      else
      {
      ch--;
      printf("%c", ch);}

    printf("\n");
  }


  space = 1;


  for (k = 1; k <= n - 1; k++)
  {
    for (c = 1; c <= space; c++)
      printf(" ");

    space++;
    ch='`';

    for (c = 1 ; c <= 2*(n-k)-1; c++)
      if (c <= n-k)
      {ch++;
      printf("%c", ch);
      }

      else
      {
      ch--;
      printf("%c", ch);}

    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What should I do in this case? I'm not very experienced in the C language. I've tried many things but every time it just ruined the whole code. I succeeded at moving the first line only! But the letters below aren't able to move. 
and another question:

how do I let the number 9 for example in the black photo appear on a distance that is equal 9 spaces to the right, and if the number I put 4 so the number will appear 4 spaces to the right?

Comment: can you point out more specifically what is going off?

Comment: @bashrc as you can see in the black photo, the letters a, aba.. they start strictly from the left side without any space, I want them to start one space to the right, every line of them.

Comment: Print `' '` before each line.

Comment: @PM77-1 where exactly before each line? Its not clear.

Comment: Do you understand this code?

Comment: You need this? http://ideone.com/TMXLlW

Comment: Does any one has an explanation for the down voting? Im new here, and Im doing my best to stick to this websites rules, and I rarely find people who respect my effort! thats really depressing!

Comment: @F1sargyan The only thing I can think of is that you had links to images instead of images, before the edit. Someone could have down-voted your question based off that reason without realizing you have too low of a reputation to add images. So I +1'ed your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're for loop `for (c = 1; c <= space; c++)` adds a `' '` from 1 to whatever `space` equals. The output you're receiving differs from the output you desire by one space. You can do two things:

Set `space` equal to n before the loop:

```
space = n - 1;
```

becomes

```
space = n;
```

or set `c` equal to zero in the loop.

```
for (c = 0; c <= space; c++)
```

Comment: thanks,!! I have another question if u don't mind! how do I let the number 9 for example in the black photo appear on a distance that is equal 9 spaces to the right, and if the number I put 4 so the number will appear 4 spaces to the right?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but the only way I could think of is to clear the screen and reprint the question together with the entered number. Then, you print the diamond. As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166990/clear-command-prompt-with-c-on-windows), `You include conio.h and call _clrscr(); Or you can call system("cls");` to clear command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 for `space`

```
for (c = 1; c <= space+1; c++)
```

and

```
for (c = 1; c <= space+1; c++)
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have another question. how do I let the number 9 for example in the black photo appear on a distance that is equal 9 spaces to the right, and if the number I put 4 so the number will appear 4 spaces to the right?

Comment: @F1sargyan, do you want to fill the right space with the entered number?

Comment: this number is just an input, that indicates the size of the shape, I want that when the output file is printed, to appear n*spaces to the right assuming that the size is n. 
so if the n=9, i want it to show the number 9, 9 spaces (blanks) to the right.

Comment: right to the sentence that ends with he word diamond:, its actually some trick has to do with scanf function.. don't u think ?

Comment: Its stupid i know, but we send these files to the university, and their system checks if the output matches theirs, and they give us expected files "that our output must look like" and let us modify our code so it be perfect match with theirs. (its just the idea of how the thing looks, but not the programming, the programming could be different)