# How to clear console in C on Windows using Netbeans+ Cygwin?

Tags: c, netbeans, cygwin

I have searched on the Internet but most of the answers suggest using library conio.h which is not available. Can anyone give me answer for this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26175996/2861476) could help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Windows

`system("cls");`

If you are on Linux/unix

`system("clear");`

Answer (score 2):

You can try ANSI escape sequences:

```
printf("\033[2J\033[H");
```

This clears the terminal window and places the cursor at the top left corner if ANSI escape sequences are supported by the terminal.  It works fine in most Unix X11 terminals, on OS/X terminals and on the cygwin terminal.

If your Windows terminal does not recognise ANSI sequences, look at this page to enable it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want a quick and dirty solution, `system("clear");` or `system("cls");` might do the trick.

Comment: It works fine for me but can you explain a little bit about that line. I have searched on google but still confused.
Edit: I found out that [2J is used to erase display but how about 033 and [H

Comment: `\033` is the escape character, `ESC [ H` set the cursor to the home position, the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: There's a good explanation of the escape sequences here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

"All sequences start with the character ESC (ASCII decimal 27/hex 0x1B/octal 033)".

One of the "non csi" sequences is simply "c" which performs a reset.

So the most basic clear screen is: printf "\033c"

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you wont to use clear screen:

```
printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
```

How it works:

- The `\e[1;1H` sets the screen to the 1st row and 1st column.
- The `2J` overwrites with " "(Space) all characters currently on the
  screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<cstlib>      //or    
#include<stdlib.h>
…


…
system("clear");
…
```

Note: Frankly I would suggest you to start using Latest Microsoft Visual Studio, you will be able to use all function of c without any issues.